# "tr -s '\n' ' ' < $file" giving different output when running standalone and in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am creating a shell script where I am using tr command to remove new line character and then use grep command to find dialog tag something like this

```
_linesContainingDialog="$(tr -s '\n' ' ' < $file | grep -oP '(?<=<af:dialog).*?(?= </af:dialog>)')"
```

When running this line alone in terminal

```
tr -s '\n' ' ' < $file | grep -oP '(?<=<af:dialog).*?(?= </af:dialog>)'
```

It gives me 7 distinct line

But when I run this in shell script and echo _linesContainingDialog, it gives me only one line. It seems, all 7 lines are jumbled up into one line when I run in shell script.

Request you to let me know what can I do different to get 7 distinct lines in shell script

Comment: You have to quote the parameter as in `echo "$_linesContainingDialog`".

Comment: Moreover you can avoid using `tr` by using `-z` option in `grep`

Comment: @anubhava Doesn't `grep -z` expect lines to be terminated by NUL `\0`

Comment: `-z` treats the input as a set of lines